# SSH to Linux host with an incompatible Terminal Size

Tags: linux, ssh, xterm

I use SSH from MacOS within its built-in Terminal program to login to a CentOS server. For some reasons, after login, this server has some setting that makes it 80 column only. If my Terminal is wider than 80 columns, strange things will happen. Like if I type a bunch of characters, the strings will break at the 80 col mark and then resume on the first character of the same line.

I researched on this issue and the best I can come up with is using xterm escape sequence:

```
echo -e "\e[8;30;90t";
```

Which resizes my Terminal to 30x90. I change my terminal size frequently and I don't want to keep track of my current terminal size. I also don't want my terminal to resize.

Is there a better way to fix that?

Comment: This seems crazy but common. It is usually caused  by the Terminal connection type that can be adjusted in macOS. Open up Terminal, go to “Preferences”  and then—in whatever profile you are in—go to the “Advanced” tab and under “Terminfo” change the value of “Declare terminal as:” to  something other than what it is set to. In macOS Mojave I have: `xterm-256color`. So try something like just plain `xterm` or even  `vt102`.  Look at [this answer as well](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81368).

Answer (score 0):

Try typing

```
reset
```

after launching the terminal (maybe add to your .bashrc file). This should clear the screen and reset the terminal size information used by the shell to something appropriate.

Comment: That didn't work. I suspect `resize` will work but there is no `resize` on that host.